# Crystal Reports : cascading parameters, one dropdown feeds multiple others

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I must allow a user to select values from 4 separate dropdowns.  All 4 dropdowns will be determined by a previous 'parent' dropdown (not included in those 4).  Also, my 4 dropdowns will all have the exact same contents (determined by the parent). User will select an item in each dropdown, my report will run and produce statistics on those 4 selections.  The 'parent' dropdown will have several choices and each choice will dynamically load  options in the 4 dropdowns.

I can use the cascading parameters to get the 'parent' and 1 of the 4 next dropdowns, but I cant go any further.  Prefer not to have 4 separate cascading parameters, I must ensure that the 4 dropdowns are all based on the same parent value.

How do I get the selection from the first 'parent' dropdown to control the contents of ALL 4 of the other dropdowns?

I tried to feed the value from the initial 'parent' dropdown into a Command object to create a data source for the other dropdowns, did not work, cant get that initial value into a Command.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: couldn't get you... your requirement will be achived by cascading parameters.... parent drop down will be used in all other drop downs

Comment: Can you give me more details?  I tried for hours to get the cascading to work between dropdowns.  I dont see the way to link the other dropdowns to the parent of the first cascaded dropdown.

Comment: See if there is a cascading parameter created then all 4 parameters are interlinked...if you are checking for 4th then 2 and 3 are coming in between again all are linked...if you see only 4th then create only 2 1st and 4th and check

Comment: I will research more, but I think your suggestions wont help.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did:

I configured a regular cascading dropdown, with the parent feeding the second dropdown.  The second dropdown was configured to accept multiple values, so the user could select 4 from the list.  Within crystal, I programtically accessed those 4 values and did what I needed to.  I cant stop user from selecting more then 4, I ignore them. All 4 are in an array object.

So, instead of 4 identical dropdowns, I used one dropdown and allowed multiple selections.